# TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

My code and error is below and I was trying to understand why I am getting the error and how to fix it. I tried this without self and got another error

```
TypeError: load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.
```

```py
def main(self):

    training_loader, validation_loader, testing_loader = Utilities3.load_data(data)
    model, optimizer, criterion = Utilities3.network_construct(structure, drop, hidden_layer, learningrate, device)
    Utilities3.do_deep_learning(model, optimizer, criterion, epochs, 40, training_loader, device)
    Utilities3.save_checkpoint(model, path, structure, hidden_layer, drop, learningrate)
    print("Training is finish")


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-77e46aea71ac> in <module>()
     49 
     50 if __name__== "__main__":
---> 51     main()

TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: You define `main` as having an argument, `self`, but call it without any: `main()`. The second error you mention is that `Utilities3.load_data` (whose definition we can't see) apparently *doesn't* take any position arguments, but you *are* passing one. You need to pass the arguments to functions that they expect!

Comment: Did you rip out a method from a class and now try to use it as a function?

Comment: you have to pass an argument to `self` in your `main(self)` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `main` takes in the argument `self`, but in your execution, `main()`, you do not pass in any arguments.

First, `self` is used in object oriented programming, when you have a class with attributes and methods. But that is not what you have here. Moreover, you don't seem to be using `self` at all in the function, so why do you have it as an argument?

Do this instead:

```py
def main():

    training_loader, validation_loader, testing_loader = Utilities3.load_data(data)
    model, optimizer, criterion = Utilities3.network_construct(structure, drop, hidden_layer, learningrate, device)
    Utilities3.do_deep_learning(model, optimizer, criterion, epochs, 40, training_loader, device)
    Utilities3.save_checkpoint(model, path, structure, hidden_layer, drop, learningrate)
    print("Training is finish")


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks mate. yeah, I was trying to work it out and thought adding 'self' would help. Because when I remove it, I get the error and I have not comprehended what the error actually means. TypeError: load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a6836d8b2061> in <module>()
     49 
     50 if __name__== "__main__":
---> 51     main()

Comment: <ipython-input-1-a6836d8b2061> in main()
     41 def main():
     42 
---> 43     training_loader, validation_loader, testing_loader = Utilities3.load_data(data)
     44     model, optimizer, criterion = Utilities3.network_construct(structure, drop, hidden_layer, learningrate, device)
     45     Utilities3.do_deep_learning(model, optimizer, criterion, epochs, 40, training_loader, device)

TypeError: load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given