# Implementing Logistic Regression "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"

Tags: python, regression, typeerror

What i am Doing?
Trying to implement Logistic Regression algorithm to classify features as PASS or FAIL.

Code:

```
def fit(self, theta, x, y):
    opt_weights = fmin_tnc(func = cost_function, x0 = theta, fprime = gradient, args = (x, y.flatten()))
    return opt_weights
parameters = fit(X, y, theta)
```

Error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 parameters = fit(X, y, theta)
>
> TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

What is the mistake here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840027/typeerror-main-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `self` parameter.

That is for when your method is part of a class. Based on your usage example, it is just a function that does not belong to a class.

```py
def fit(theta, x, y):
    opt_weights = fmin_tnc(func = cost_function, x0 = theta, fprime = gradient, args = (x, y.flatten()))
    return opt_weights

parameters = fit(X, y, theta)
```